# Store command output on SFTP resource

Tags: ssh, pipe, sftp

I just wanted to create a tar ball and only store it on an SFTP resource. Because I'm paranoid about data corruption, I usually store the sha256sums of my tar balls with them if it's something I want to be able to rely on, and calculate them both when generating the archives and after they have been written by reading them from the storage media they're stored on.

I assumed this to be pretty straight-forward, so I typed this command on:

```
tar --exclude='./somefolder' -zc . | tee "sftp://mydomain.ending/storage/location/on/server/sth.tar" | sha256sum
```

I also tried what Nautilus uses for its remote terminals:

```
tar --exclude='./somefolder' -zc . | tee ":/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=mydomain.ending/storage/location/on/server/sth.tar" | sha256sum
```

However, the outputs were:

```
tee: 'sftp://mydomain.ending/storage/location/on/server/sth.tar': No such file or directory
```

and

```
tee: ':/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=mydomain.ending/storage/location/on/server/sth.tar': No such file or directory
```

respectively.

How do I store the tar ball there without storing it locally first? Preferably without mounting the remote resource in some folder first so it can be used easily.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 (with Linux 4.4.0).

Comment: Have you tried removing the initial `:` in your final `tee` invocation?  This looks like Nautilus mounts the remote destination by gvfs, in which case it is mounted sort of transparently as `/run/…`, as you show.  I'm not sure what the initial `:` is for

Comment: @Fox Thank you very much for pointing that out! I really was too stupid to copy and paste a path. -.- It works if you remove that colon. Want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nautilus uses `gvfs` to mount remote storage locations, such as the SFTP server in your question.  This allows you to treat the remote server as if it were part of your local filesystem.  The path it mounts to is usually

```
/run/user/<your uid>/gvfs/<server specification>/<path>
```

I am fairly certain the prefix is always

```
/run/user/<your uid>
```

so you can find this mount point by `ls` or <kbd>Tab</kbd>-ing through that directory.

Once you have found this mount point, you can use `tee` as you normally would (with line-breaks added for clarity):

```
tar --exclude='./somefolder' -zc .  \
| tee "/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=mydomain.ending/storage/location/on/server/sth.tar"  \
| sha256sum
```

---

Alternatively, you can avoid a GVFS mount and still avoid the non-portable process substitution by using SSH instead of SFTP:

```
tar --exclude='./somefolder' -zc .  \
| ssh mydomain.ending 'tee "/storage/location/on/server/sth.tar"' 2>/dev/null  \
| sha256sum
```

Unfortunately, `sftp` the program does not allow one to push files to a remote host via a single command line, only retrieve them.

As @rudimeier points out, the above `ssh` method uploads *and downloads* the file to avoid storing it locally.  If you'd rather not re-download it, it might be better to do the `sha256sum` remotely:

```
tar --exclude='./somefolder' -zc .  \
| ssh mydomain.ending 'tee "/storage/location/on/server/sth.tar" | sha256sum' 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: So you are happy with a solution which only works while nautilus is running and connected?

Comment: I think adding a description of how to find that path is a good idea so others can easily apply this answer.

Comment: @Fox Oops, I already submitted text for that.

Comment: @rudimeier Yes. It seems like a really practical solution because if gives you a path to work with. Of course, your solution is better if you want to do it entirely on the terminal, which is something I definitely see, or if you don't use Nautilus or some other program which provides a `gvfs` mount point.

Comment: @Fox your "ssh" solution is bad because `tee` basically you upload *and download* the file. You could run sha256sum remote too. But I would it do locally. I will add such ssh line to my answer too.

Comment: @rudimeier Originally I used a FIFO and let `sha256sum` read from that while `ssh` transferred the contents to the remote server.  But then I realized that the FIFO would be stored on the local disk, and OP mentioned "without storing it locally first".  Your use of process substitution is in general cleaner, but I try to stick to POSIX where I can

Comment: @FOX the FIFO does not use disk space, it's just a named pipe. The /dev file system is only in memory. POSIXLY without bash you could use `mkfifo` but then you don't have a single command line but at least 3.

Comment: @rudimeier Regarding multiple commands: yes, but that's what scripts are for.  See revision 2 of the edit history on this answer.  I switched away from that because I wasn't sure the contents were memory-only

Answer (score 2):

Without fancy gvfs or sshfs mounts you need to use an sftp client. I choose `lftp` >=4.7 because it works with FIFO pipes (`scp` and `sftp` do not).

This works with `bash` on Linux:

```
tar --exclude='./somefolder' -zc . \
 | tee >(lftp -c 'connect sftp://user:pass@server/path/ ;put /dev/stdin -o sth.tar.gz;') \
 | sha256sum
```

Alternatively using `ssh` client (outer brackets needed for interactive password auth):

```
(tar --exclude='./somefolder' -zc . \
 | tee >(ssh user@server "cat > /path/sth.tar.gz") \
 | sha256sum)
```

Note, `tee's` argument looks also a bit exotic but this is non-portable `bash` magic to avoid additional `mkfifo` commands, explained in `man bash`:

> Process Substitution
>
> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The process list is run with its input or output connected to a FIFO or some file in /dev/fd.  The name  of  this  file  is
>          passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion.  If the >(list) form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list.  If the <(list) form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list.

Comment: How can this work? Isn't the stdout of `tee` redirected to `(sha256sum)`? How can it also be piped to `sftp`?

Comment: Thank you! I'll upvote your answer but I'll accept the other one because I'm going to use the approach described there.

Comment: @Fox Thanks! Finally I got it fixed and tested it.